Initiate non-pushing action from List/Form row, with NavigationLink styling and behaviour
I have a List. I want to initiate an action when the user taps on a list row.
The row needs to look and behave like a regular NavigationLink, complete with chevron. But, a tap should not inititate a push to another screen.
Note: this pattern is used by Apple itself. For example, in the Reminders app:

(Tapping this row will cause a sheet to be displayed, rather than a new screen being pushed on to the navigation stack.)
Crucially, this row looks and behaves as it were a NavigationLook, including highlighting the entire row on tap, with a standard-looking chevron.
Question: how can I reproduce this row?

You have to implement all the logic yourself

I am voting to reopen this question as it asks how to implement a very specific behaviour, namely, something that looks like a NavigationLink but shows a sheet instead of pushing a new view onto the navigation stack.

You can use a NavigationLink as the label of a Button.
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showSheet = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List {
                Button {
                    showSheet = true
                } label: {
                    NavigationLink("Details") {}
                }
                // remove the button's default tint
                .tint(.primary)
                
                // a normal navigation link for comparison
                NavigationLink("Details") {}
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $showSheet) {
                Text("Sheet content...")
            }
        }
    }
}

Output:


Thank you. That was an unexpected solution. Cheers.
